# How do i find the last 2nd row for every alternating column in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to find the last 2nd row of alternating column in a worksheet in this case the last 2nd row of Time1, Time2 etc and after that copy and paste it on another worksheet as shown in the picture? Often time, when each column has the same number of rows, using LastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row will do the job but this time round, every alternating columns have different number of rows so i cant used that LastRow definition. Below is my attempted code where i am stuck on how to manipulate to get the last 2nd row for every alternating column.

```
Sub main()

Dim i As Long

Dim j As Long

Dim lastrowv1 As Long

Dim LastColumn As Long


i = 1 'i for column
j = 2  'j for row



Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("current")
LastColumn = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For i = 1 To LastColumn Step 2
    With sht

'How do i find the last 2nd row for every alternate column(in this case time1,time2,time3...timex) in VBA?

'
'
'

End Sub
```

[image]

When tried to store the values on another worksheet eg:

```
     For m = 2 To i - 2 Step 2
                Sheets("Breakdown").Cells(m / 2 + 1, 3) = timecoll.Add.Cells(.Rows.count, i).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Value

'^argument not optional error above
              Next m
```

If there are empty data and i want to give that columns with empty data a name called "short", how do i go about doing it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the same kind of method you used to get the last column we can get the last row of each column from inside the loop and offset by -1 row.

Then store the values in a collection (or do whatever you want with them).

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastcolumn As Long

    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("current")

    Dim timecoll As Collection
    Set timecoll = New Collection
    With sht
        lastcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = 1 To lastcolumn Step 2
            timecoll.Add .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Value
        Next i
    End With
```

For your edit, I am unsure what that loop is so I'm going to dump to column A in `Sheets("Breakdown")`.

```
dim k as variant

set sht = thisworkbook.sheets("Breakdown")
i = 1
with sht
    for each k in timecoll
        .cells(i, 1).value = k
        i = i + 1
    next k
end with
```

Okay here's the whole thing after the edit:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastcolumn As Long

    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("current")

    Dim timecoll As Collection
    Set timecoll = New Collection
    With sht
        lastcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        On Error GoTo short
        For i = 1 To lastcolumn Step 2
            timecoll.Add .Cells(.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Value
        Next i
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    Dim k As Variant

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Breakdown")
    i = 1
    With sht
        For Each k In timecoll
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = k
            i = i + 1
        Next k
    End With
    Exit Sub
short:
    timecoll.Add "Short"
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I see one issue, collection doesn't accept duplicates so it will error if two columns have identical value on their second last row. Storing cell address might be better way.

Comment: @Warcupine when i tried to store the values on another worksheet called "Breakdown" , if gives the argument not optional error as shown on my updated post. What should i do to rectify it?

Comment: @john If you want to use the values in the collection you wouldn't use add. you will also need a with statement or add an explicit reference to the ```.rows.count```.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Actually I didn't key the collection so it can store dupes.

Comment: @warcupine for some reason, i still get the argument not optional error if i just use your code except for the part where i didnt leave a space in timecoll.add.cells but when i leave a space as shown in your code, it shows application or object defined error...

Comment: @John ```collection.add``` is a method of an object that has one required parameter. The space is telling it that what comes after is the parameters, so it meets that parameter requirement. A collection also does not have a ```.cells``` property. You don't want to add anything else (I think), you just want to output what is stored in there which that second loop does.

Comment: @john If you're getting an application error on the first part of the code it could be that you have a column with only a single row, the offset would be causing the error in that case because there is no row 0.

Comment: @Warcupine oh ya i forget to tell you there are case where there is empty column in my data so do you mean that causes the application error? Is there a way to error handle it?

Comment: @john yeah, that will cause an error. probably easiest to just put an ```on error resume next``` just before the loop and then an ```on error goto 0``` just after. Since it is completely empty you can't even check to see if the last row is > 1 since trying to get the row value of an empty column will also throw an error.

Comment: @Warcupine sorry, what i mean is that instead of using error resume, i want to give the columns with empty data a value lets say "short" as way to error handle it, how do i do it with your code in this case? I updated my post with a picture with regards to this case. Thanks alot btw..

Comment: So it will store the values 121.37, 144.8, "short", 84.428 in my breakdown worksheet instead of just ending abruptly due to the application or object defined error..

Comment: That should do it (disregard that ```, "test" & i``` I was seeing something and forgot it was in there, editted out now).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214266/discussion-between-warcupine-and-john).

Comment: @Warcupine sorry i was late for discussion, anyways your code works pretty well, thanks alot for your effort

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want the result something like this :
[image]

I do the code like this :

```
Sub test()
tRow = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Rows.Count
Set DestSh = Sheets("test") 'change as needed
DestCol = "J" 'change as needed
Set oStart = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
oCol = Left(oStart.Columns.Address(0, 0), 1)

Do
DestSh.Range(DestCol & tRow).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value _
= Range(oCol & tRow).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)
Set oStart = oStart.Offset(0, 2)
oCol = Left(oStart.Columns.Address(0, 0), 1)
Loop Until oStart.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Edit: if there is no data :

```
Sub test5()
tRow = ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Rows.Count
Set DestSh = Sheets("test") 'change as needed
DestCol = "P" 'change as needed
Set oStart = Sheets("test").Range("A1") 'change as needed
oCol = Left(oStart.Columns.Address(0, 0), 1)

Do
If Range(oCol & 2).Value = "" Then
DestSh.Range(DestCol & tRow).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "short"
Else
DestSh.Range(DestCol & tRow).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value _
= Range(oCol & tRow).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0)
End If
Set oStart = oStart.Offset(0, 2)
oCol = Left(oStart.Columns.Address(0, 0), 1)
Loop Until oStart.Value = ""

End Sub
```

[image]

The condition which I don't "calculate" is
 
IF it only has one row data THEN... (what ?) :)

Comment: If there are empty data and i want to give that columns with empty data a name called "short", how do i go about doing it? so in this case, the value stored will give me 100, 200 , short ,300... I have updated my post with a picture in this case btw..Thanks..

Comment: @john, please have a look to the second code in my post. I hope I get what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If all the data has headings in the first row find the last column number and then loop though all those columns as below.

```
Sub test()
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("current")
Dim myCells As Range
Lcol = sht.Cells(1, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
i = 1
Do While i <= Lcol
    PrevofLRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    'union of those cells can be made as below
    If myCells Is Nothing Then
      Set myCells = Cells(PrevofLRow, i)
      Else
      Set myCells = Union(myCells, Cells(PrevofLRow, i))
    End If
i = i + 2
Loop

End Sub
```